# Slimscroll does not work in an ui-view with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, slimscroll

I want to use SlimScroll in my project. The problem is that the content that needs to scoll is in a ui-view.

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" id="conversation-content">
    <div id="scroll">
        <div ui-view="conversation-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what the problem is. The `#scroll` div gets a height and width but it does not scroll and the SlimScroll bar is not visible.

This is the SlimScroll JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#scroll").slimScroll({
        height: "auto",
        color: "#00f",
        size: "10px",
        alwaysVisible: true
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more detail, I can only advise adding these Script blocks in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function ()
{
    $("#scroll").slimScroll({
        height: "auto",
        color: "#00f",
        size: "10px",
        alwaysVisible: true
    });
});
</script>
```

This requires the `jquery.slimscroll.js` to be in the same folder/directory as this HTML or web page. Swap the `jquery.slimscroll.js` for `jquery.slimscroll.min.js` if you are using the minified version.

Comment: I figured it out. The `#scroll` div has to have a height and a `position: relative`. Now it works great.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to use slimscroll in AngularJS and does not want jQuery as dependency, here's a [link](http://demo.jankuri.com/ngSlimscroll/)